# How to install BBEdit Syntax highlighting

Tags: installation, julia

I'd like to try this https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-textwrangler-bbedit but I didn't understand how to install it.

For installation it says to copy this `BBEditTextWrangler-julia.plist` to this folder `~/Library/Application\ Support/BBEdit/Language\ Modules/` in BBEdit. But what do I copy? Do I copy the content of that file? Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-textwrangler-bbedit/master/BBEditTextWrangler-julia.plist) (the "raw" version of the `plist` file) to your `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Language Modules/` folder.

However, note that the file hasn't been updated in five years, and so may not be up to date with current Julia syntax. It has had a couple of updates to support Julia 1.0 and above, but still has remnants of old Julia 0.4 syntax that it was written for (for eg. mentioning `repmat` as a function which hasn't existed in the language for a long time). So it's still going to be useful overall, but not 100% reliable.